# use jquery to modify class attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<ul>
<li><a class="selected">A</a></li>
<li><a>B</a></li>
<li><a>C</a></li>
</ul>
```

How can I remove the attribute selected from all `<li>'s` when one of the element is clicked and set the one being clicked to selected?

I'm learning jquery.

**Updated the code**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Update:

You can modify the code like this for the links:

```
$(function(){
  $('#container ul > li > a').click(function(){
    $(this).siblings('.selected').removeClass('selected');
    $(this).addClass('selected');
  });
});
```

---

You can do this way:

```
$(function(){
  $('#container ul > li').click(function(){
    $(this).siblings('.selected').removeClass('selected');
    $(this).addClass('selected');
  });
});
```

The [`siblings()`](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/) method is used to find the surrounding siblings of the clicked element and then [`removeClass`](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/) is used to remove the selected class that has one. Later [`addClass`](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/) is used to apply the selected class to clicked element referred to with `$(this)`. The `container` in code above is supposed to be the id of element which contains your list.

Note also that click event fits for links or buttons rather than lists :)

Comment: I forgot that the attribute selected is actually inside an <a> tag. I updated my question.

Answer (score 0):

Use [addClass](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/) and [removeClass](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/).

Answer (score 0):

removeAttr('class') or removeClass('selected')